# Getting Null Values on a Left Join

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join

I have the query below. I am trying to left join to another table. I know for a fact that the query should return values but the values are coming back as null. Does anyone see anything I am doing wrong? My brain is fried at this point.

```
SELECT 
    ss.NDC,
    ss.ShipToAddressNo,
    ss.QuantityShipped,
    c.AccrualType,
    ss.ExtendedPrice ExtendedPrice,
    c.AccrualAmount CBAccrualAmount
FROM
    SalesSummary ss left join ChargebackAccruals c on
        ss.ClassOfTrade = c.TradeClass and
        c.AddressNo is null and
        c.ShipTo is null and
        c.ShortItemNo is null and
        c.LotNumber is null and
        ss.InvoiceDate = @RunDate and
        ss.InvoiceDate between AccrualBeginDate and AccrualEndDate
```

Comment: Could you give a sample dataset where you are seeing the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any condition in the ON-clause is part of the join, so any row with data in AddressNo or ShipTp or ShortItemNo orLotNumber will be NULLed.

You probably want to move them into WHERE.

What do you want as result?

Answer (score 0):

Left outer join produces a complete set of records from Table A, with the matching records (where available) in Table B. If there is no match, the right side will contain null.

Comment: There is a match, though. When I do a normal join then I get actual column values where as when I do a left join they return null...

Comment: Of course they return null. You're saying only join where ` c.ShipTo is null`